# count coalesce to count from two columns

Tags: sql, count, coalesce

I have two columns

```
product    productactual
```

and the following data:

```
shoes        NULL
slippers     NULL
shoes        sandals
slippers     NULL
sandals      shoes
```

I have to count the Number of products 
I am using `Count (coalesce(Productactual,product))` but its not working any changes in query or new idea to count products in two columns.

Comment: What is not working? What do you get, what did you expect? In the example, the query should return 5.

Comment: did you mean COUNT DISTINCT ?

Comment: please specify more exactly what you want to count? what is "not working" about your existing query, what is it returning, what should it return, and why, in your opinion? do you want to count those products having productactual NULL? then try `select count(product) where productactual is null`

Comment: why would you want to coalesce the count? this only makes sense if `product` could be `NULL` your `COUNT(COALESCE` would always return 5 in this case because you have `NULL`-values in `productactual`, maybe you meant to select both counts seperately? `COUNT(product), COUNT(productactual)` would get both the `COUNT` for each row where `productactual IS NOT NULL` and those where `product IS NOT ALL` (every row in your example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count entries *per product*, you need to use your COALESCE expression as a grouping item:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(productactual, product) AS product,
  COUNT(*) AS productcount
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  COALESCE(productactual, product)
;
```